# URL to download latest version of WP for other languages than English

Tags: installation, language

I'm considering he possibility of automating/scripting a basic WP install. Part of it will include downloading the latest WordPress version.

The en-us version can be obtained by downloading http://wordpress.org/latest.zip (or tar.gz), is there any way to get an always up-to-date file URL for other languages?

Comment: There is `http://de.wordpress.org/latest-de_DE.zip` but this doesn’t work with all languages.

Comment: Weird, http://de.wordpress.org/latest-pt_BR.zip will get me the pt_BR latest version, but http://wordpress.org/latest-pt_BR.zip will return RELEASE NOT FOUND.

Comment: I've posted this question at [WP Polyglots](http://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/2013/11/07/download-links-for-the-latest-release-in-different-locales/).

Comment: Relevant: a [list of WP languages and sites](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language). Possibly outdated and / or broken

Answer (score 2):

Can you include [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) in your script? Then it *could* be as easy as:

```
wp core config --dbname=wordpress_default --locale="<your locale>" --dbuser=sqluser --dbpass=sqlpass --quiet
wp core install --url=local.wordpress.dev --quiet --title="Local WordPress Dev" --admin_name=admin --admin_email="admin@local.dev" --admin_password="password"
```

Docs for [wp core config](http://wp-cli.org/commands/core/config/) and [wp core install](http://wp-cli.org/commands/core/install/)